# Include api routes in a nuxt and express app (using create-nuxt-app)

Tags: express, nuxt.js

I created an app using the create-nuxt-app npm command and I got this server/index.js file.

```
const express = require('express')
const consola = require('consola')
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt')
const app = express()
const host = process.env.HOST || '127.0.0.1'
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.set('port', port)

// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
let config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
config.dev = !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')

async function start() {
  // Init Nuxt.js
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

  // Build only in dev mode
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
    await builder.build()
  }

  // Give nuxt middleware to express
  app.use(nuxt.render)

  // Listen the server
  app.listen(port, host)
  consola.ready({
    message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
    badge: true
  })
}
start()
```

I also have a js file containing my api routes.

```
const { Router } = require('express')
const router = Router()
router.get('/route1', function(req, res){
   return 'Hello world';
}
module.exports = router
```

I am looking for a way to prefix the routes with 'api', without adding it to each route one by one (if possible) as well as including the routes in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Just apply your api route as middleware with prefix path

```
import api from './api';
app.use('/api', api);
```

Ref: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#path-examples

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation:

> https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-servermiddleware/
>
> https://nuxtjs.org/examples/auth-routes

API routes apply to `nuxt.config.js`

```
serverMiddleware: [
    '~/api'
],
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can add
in server/index.js file.

```
app.use(nuxt.render)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).